# Multiple SIP Trunk with Single SBC IP - FreePBX

Tags: routes, asterisk, voip, freepbx, iproute

Help me to configure 3 SIP Trunks (200 Channels per Trunk) from Telco, Where all the 3 SIP has different outbound Caller ID and all the Three trunks needs to route via Single Private  / SBC IP (100.0.2.4)

[Here is my IP Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z1Ct.png)

I am using FreePBX, with Asterisk 15 with Asterisk 17 - I able to route 100.0.2.4 via below command

```
ip route del 100.0.2.4 nexthop via 100.0.1.24 dev eth1 weight 1 nexthop via 100.0.1.44 dev eth2 weight 1 nexthop via 100.0.1.83 dev eth3 weight 1
```

I was able to make and receive calls, but all the calls routed via any one NIC at once
which means i able to achieve max of 200 Calls at once, where my total capacity is 600 via three trunks.

Help me to achieve this in proper technical way

here is my working SIP Trunk with Telco

```
qualify=yes
insecure=invite,port
host=100.0.2.4
dtfmmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
context=from-trunk
canreinvite=yes
allow=g729
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is use PJSIP channel driver with different endpoint section(each one to different ip).

Other way is use 3 asterisk with chan_sip each one binded to own ip.

http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?t=71510